# Empty vector<Point> size() in loop condition causes weird behavier

Tags: c++, opencv

I get some weird behavier that I don't understand, maybe I am simply missing something obvious. I am hoping someone can explain it.

Here is some code that causes the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

// draw line from point to point along the point "list"
void drawLineSegments(Mat img, vector<Point> points, Scalar colour = Scalar(255,255,255)){
    for (int i = 0; i < (points.size()-1); i ++){
        line(img,points[i],points[i+1], colour);
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Mat testImg = Mat(100,100,CV_8U,0.0); // test black image, not important

    vector<Point> testPoints; // new vector

    drawLineSegments(testImg,testPoints); // try to draw it, expect function to do nothing because size should be 0

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles but gives an error at runtime "vector subscript out of range", through debugging I can see that it is because the for loop runs. Why does the for loop run? This is what I don't understand.

Calling testPoints.size() seems to return 0 and if I change the draw function to:

```
// draw line from point to point along the point "list"
void drawLineSegments(Mat img, vector<Point> points, Scalar colour = Scalar(255,255,255)){
    int lengthMinusOne = points.size()-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthMinusOne; i ++){
        line(img,points[i],points[i+1], colour);
    }
}
```

Then it works. So why can't I use points.size() directly in the condition?

Comment: Consider using vector's iterator to avoid these headaches. Something like for (auto i = points.begin(); i + 1 != points.end(); ++i) { ... }

Comment: @user823981: That also fails if the vector is empty, since `i+1` is invalid.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Good point. <:) You'd have to check that (i != v.end() && i + 1 != v.end()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

size() return a size_t which is unsigned subtracting 1 from zero causes an underflow.  When you do the assigment to int it correctly setts it to -1 in the loop you are effectively comparing UINT_MAX to i.

Answer (score 4):

This line is the culprit.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (points.size()-1); i ++){
```

Specifically, `(points.size()-1)`

That is equivalent to saying:

```
size_t s = points.size(); // Which is zero for you use case.
s = s - 1;  // This is not -1. It's large positive number.
for (int i = 0; i < s; i ++){
```

Since `s != -1`, you will enter the code block in the `for` loop and access member from `points`, which leads to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You should have seen a warning regarding signed/unsigned comparison (The for loop has a flaw).